# Swing JList slows down extremely if 1st entry selected (Windows 10)

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel, openjdk-11

**Goal:**
Use JList for any purpose.

**Problem:**
If the first entry is selected, and then you clear the model and add new content, this will be *extremely* slow, no matter how often you do it. Only once you have selected another entry - one that *is not the first* - the behavior will be fast=normal again.

**Workaround:**
Every time before clearing the model, programmatically add two arbitrary entries (two, because the list may have been entirely empty), then select the entry with the highest valid index.

**Question:**
Can you reproduce the bug? Is it a known bug? If not, could someone please post it so that OpenJDK will be fixed?

**Test environment:**
Standard Oracle Java release download JDK8 202.
`java version "1.8.0_202"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b08, mixed mode)`
Windows 10 Home, Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.437)
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00 GHz  4.01 GHz

Also reproduced with **OpenJDK 11**
`openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15`
`OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)`
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)`

## SSCCE

This code is minimal, so it even uses the default LookAndFeel. Originally, I encountered the problem when using L&F "Windows".

```
package jlistslowdownbugdemo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;




final public class Main {


    final private static boolean ENABLE_FIX = false;


    public static void main(final String[] args) {


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {


            final DefaultListModel<String> valueListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            final JList<String> valueList = new JList<>(valueListModel);


            final DefaultListModel<String> keyListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            for (String key : Main.DATA.keySet()) {
                keyListModel.addElement(key);
            }
            final JList<String> keyList = new JList<>(keyListModel);


            keyList.addListSelectionListener(e -> {

                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) { // To prevent SUPER-slowdown when the bug kicks. Not an important measure, just for comfortable demoing.


                    // Workaround for the bug: Add two entries (two, because list may be entirely empty),
                    // and select the last available entry (in the worst case, this is the 2nd).
                    // Just so that one is selected that IS NOT THE FIRST.
                    // This problem AND fix occurred in Oracle JDK 8 and Open JDK 11.
                    if (ENABLE_FIX) {
                        valueListModel.addElement(null);
                        valueListModel.addElement(null); // Make sure you add something else instead of null if your GUI/JList setup requires it.
                        valueList.setSelectedIndex(valueListModel.size() - 1);
                    }


                    valueListModel.clear();

                    final String key = keyList.getSelectedValue();
                    if (key != null) {
                        for (String value : Main.DATA.get(key)) {
                            valueListModel.addElement(value);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });


            final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
            contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(keyList));
            contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(valueList));


            final JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setContentPane(contentPane);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 1000));
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);


            final String msg = "Click&drag in the left list. This rapidly changes the content of the right list.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "Now select any entry EXCEPT the first entry of the right list. Click&drag again in the left list,\n" +
                    "it still works just as rapidly. Now click THE FIRST entry of the right list.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "If you NOW click&drag again in the left list, you will experience BRUTAL slowdown.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "Once Swing has calmed down, click any entry EXCEPT the first entry of the right list.\n" +
                    "Click&drag again in the left list - the problem is gone.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "The built-in workaround (off by default) simulates this.";

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window,
                                          msg,
                                          "How to reproduce the Swing bug:",
                                          JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


        });

    }


    final private static Random RAND = new Random(0);


    final private static Map<String, List<String>> DATA = createDataMap();


    private static Map<String, List<String>> createDataMap() {

        final Map<String, List<String>> ret = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {


            final int listSize = 20 + RAND.nextInt(5000);


            final String key = generateRandomString('A');
            final List<String> value = new ArrayList<>(listSize);
            ret.put(key, value);


            for (int ii = 0; ii < listSize; ii++) {
                value.add(generateRandomString('a'));
            }

        }

        return ret;
    }


    private static String generateRandomString(final char baseChar) {

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        final int len = 4 + RAND.nextInt(17);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append((char) (baseChar + RAND.nextInt(26)));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

(Title edited: Removed ", definitely a Java bug")

Comment: Thanks. (Edited the title.) ... But, umm, I'm changing the model of the **other** list. No changes take place to anything about the list that has the event listener.

Comment: What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: It's supposed to demonstrate the bug, obviously.

Comment: But 1+ for an interesting problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the source of the problem yet (hence this is being answered as a "community wiki" and not yet as a personal answer), but the problem goes away if you set the JList's visible row count and prototype cell value (which is Swing best-practice).

Note that removing the value list's selection listeners before changing the model, and then re-adding them after changing the model, does not help your problem. My gut feeling is that it is an issue of rendering and sizing.

Working code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

final public class Foo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            final DefaultListModel<String> valueListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            final JList<String> valueList = new JList<>(valueListModel);
            final DefaultListModel<String> keyListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
            for (String key : Foo.DATA.keySet()) {
                keyListModel.addElement(key);
            }
            final JList<String> keyList = new JList<>(keyListModel);
            keyList.addListSelectionListener(e -> {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    valueListModel.clear();
                    final String key = keyList.getSelectedValue();
                    if (key != null) {
                        for (String value : Foo.DATA.get(key)) {
                            valueListModel.addElement(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            keyList.setVisibleRowCount(25);
            valueList.setVisibleRowCount(25);
            String prototypeFormat = "%100s";
            keyList.setPrototypeCellValue(String.format(prototypeFormat, " "));
            valueList.setPrototypeCellValue(String.format(prototypeFormat, " "));
            final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
            contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(keyList));
            contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(valueList));
            final JFrame window = new JFrame();
            window.setContentPane(contentPane);
            window.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            // window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1200, 1000));
            window.pack();
            window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            window.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    final private static Random RAND = new Random(0);
    final private static Map<String, List<String>> DATA = createDataMap();

    private static Map<String, List<String>> createDataMap() {
        final Map<String, List<String>> ret = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            final int listSize = 20 + RAND.nextInt(5000);
            final String key = generateRandomString('A');
            final List<String> value = new ArrayList<>(listSize);
            ret.put(key, value);
            for (int ii = 0; ii < listSize; ii++) {
                value.add(generateRandomString('a'));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static String generateRandomString(final char baseChar) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        final int len = 4 + RAND.nextInt(17);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append((char) (baseChar + RAND.nextInt(26)));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is somehow with the value list's prototype cell value as now I've whittled the solution down to one line: setting this value:

```
valueList.setPrototypeCellValue("                ");
```

Again, I don't know why this works, but the problem must reside here since this solves everything. Perhaps it has to do with how the list interacts with the JScrollPane since the prototype cell value is key to calculating the scrollable viewport size and the preferred size.

Comment: Indeed, this one line (even with only one space) makes the problem go away. Good to know. I still think it's a bug because of the weird circumstances and effects. Btw., JavaDocs say: "computes the fixedCellWidth and fixedCellHeight properties by requesting the cell renderer component for the given value (and index 0) from the cell renderer" - *So there is something special about index 0 in regards to this method!*

Comment: ... Nope, entire behavior (incl. my workaround and your fix) stays the same without JScrollPanes.

Comment: @DreamspacePresident then to get a full solution, someone will likely need to dig through the source code. That someone won't be me, as I'm on vacation and am about to go hiking. Good luck, and will be watching.

Comment: Yea right, let's loose the whole day for this. The problem is indeed in BasicListUI and the ListDataListener that gets registered to the ListModel. Thank you for this line. Removing the data listeners, then add element, then add listeners back (probably before adding last element) works too.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you execute this:

```
valueListModel.addElement(value);
```

You are making the right JList redraw itself.  Doing this dozens of times is the reason for your slowdown.

You need to change the entire model at once.  Replace this:

```
final String key = keyList.getSelectedValue();
if (key != null) {
    for (String value : Main.DATA.get(key)) {
        valueListModel.addElement(value);
    }
}
```

with this:

```
final String key = keyList.getSelectedValue();
if (key != null) {
    valueListModel.addAll(Main.DATA.get(key));
}
```

This causes the model to send one ListDataEvent to the JList, instead of an event for every element, so the JList only redraws itself once.

**Update:**

In Java 8, you want to achieve the same “set the entire model at once” effect by simply creating a new ListModel.  Replace this:

```
valueListModel.clear();

final String key = keyList.getSelectedValue();
if (key != null) {
    for (String value : Main.DATA.get(key)) {
        valueListModel.addElement(value);
    }
}
```

with this:

```
DefaultListModel<String> newListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();

final String key = keyList.getSelectedValue();
if (key != null) {
    for (String value : JListSlowDown.DATA.get(key)) {
        newListModel.addElement(value);
    }
}

valueList.setModel(newListModel);
```

Comment: Two things are wrong about your answer, but it raises good points and allowed for a 3rd solution, so it's fine. 1) By making my JList an anonymous class and overriding the paint and paintComponent methods, with calls to super and a println, I could determine that the methods are only called once per click in the left list, not for every entry. Also, why would the problem sometimes occur and sometimes not? 2) The DefaultListModel does not have an addAll method. However, you inspired to just replace the entire list model each time. THIS EVADES THE PROBLEM, TOO!

Comment: Sure looks like there’s a [DefaultListModel.addAll method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29).  And the Swing painting system is complex and highly optimized.  Did you also check how often the cell renderer was being called?

Comment: No, I didn't check that. I wouldn't know which of the methods to monitor, and I would have to separate multiple calls for the same object vs multiple calls because of multiple entries-per-list. And I just saw that the addAll method indeed exists - since Java 11. I'm primarily working with 8.

Comment: Updated for Java 8.  You can build a new ListModel and call the JList’s setModel method with it, achieving the same effect, namely, one list data event instead of many.

Comment: Which is what I wrote in my first comment. But thank you. And the readers will appreciate the edit.